# self.delegate=self in UITableView, what is wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, code-reuse

My app is required to be universal for both iPhone and iPad. For some views, iPhone version shares the same view(for example, a tableview) as iPad version. So for better reusability, I write my tableview like this, and use it in both iPhone-controller and iPad-controller.

**.h**

```
@interface NotificationView : UITableView
@end
```

**.m**

```
@interface NotificationView()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@end
@implementation NotificationView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.rowHeight = 80;
        self.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate
```

I feel that it's not right to write like this but can't tell why...
I've searched for some time, but didn't get anything useful. So, my question is:

- Why is it not right to write like this?
- What's the best practice for reusing `UITableView`?

Thanks in advance if anyone could explain it.

Comment: where u have taken object of tableview?

Comment: If you just doing this only because of iphone and ipad support? aur do you need same table view for multiple purpose? If you only do this on the basis of size like pad or phone then you not need to do this

Comment: @AayushKatiyar In view controllers.

Comment: @trojanfoe Maybe you are right. I'm just trying. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work just fine as long as you implement all the required methods to populate the table. But the reason it is bugging you is because it is poor design - it completely blurs all lines in MVC design.  Your tableView is a view. It should be dumb, and it uses delegation to plug into whatever model objects you have with a simple adaptor for good reasons.  Ask yourself, is there any view-specific (drawing, appearance) stuff that I'm doing in this subclass of UITableView? If not then why not do a tableViewController or a tiny NSObject subclass to populate the table?
Best.

Comment: To answer your question, that's no. So, maybe I should just use tableviewcontroller instead and add it to the controller as a child. I originally aimed at a lighter controller, however, it's obvious that I've got a wrong direction.:(